# What is "Current Status" (IMMCurrentStatus) in ArcFM Downstream Trace?

Tags: arcobjects, geometric-network, arcfm

I'm trying to develop a custom downstream trace Addin for ArcGIS using .net (C#) Miner.Interop.Framework Assembly.

I'm using [TraceDownstream Method](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.2.1a/DesktopSDK/topic11232.html) from the ArcFM Desktop Developer Guide and following [this example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/MMFeederTracerClass/TraceDownstream/php-mmfeedertracerclass-tracedownstream-method-examples.html) for guidance, since I'm very new in this.

By calling the Trace Downstream Function:

```
pElecTrace.TraceDownstream(pGN, pElecTraceSettings, pCurrentStatus,
                           179998,  ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriElementType.esriETJunction, 
                           Miner.Interop.SetOfPhases.None, 
                           Miner.Interop.mmDirectionInfo.establishBySourceSearch, 0,
                           ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriElementType.esriETEdge, 
                           iJunctionBarriers,iEdgeBarriers, false,
                           out pJunctions, out pEdges);
```

I get The NullReferenceException (**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**)

My Assumption is that it is because I have declared

```
IMMCurrentStatus pCurrentStatus = null;
```

by following the [mentioned Example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/MMFeederTracerClass/TraceDownstream/php-mmfeedertracerclass-tracedownstream-method-examples.html). And It is the only Null Element in the called function.

Now the problem is that , I don't have any idea what "Current Status" really is. Neither could I find any explanation in the [Documentation](http://resources.arcfmsolution.com/10.2.1a/DesktopSDK/topic9740.html) as to what Current Status really is or where can I retrieve its information from.

Comment: you ever figure this out?  i am facing the exact same issue

Comment: Yeah I gave up and stopped using ArcFM libraries :D
I wrote my own tracing algorithm in pure Arcobjects.

Comment: i tried going arcobjects first, but the output of traces was not correct.  you get good/correct traces using pure arcobjects on an arcfm enabled geodatabase?

Comment: It was correct enough for my use at least. I just had to understand how the ArcFM trace works. Hint: The "Electric Trace Weight" plays an important role. Try to understand its pattern. Unfortunately, I don't have the code now otherwise I would have shared.
But I would still suggest you to go for the proper way. If you have Schneider account, post on their forum. I didn't have an account